# electron js pass variables between renderers

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to pass variables between 2 of my html files in electron, here is what I tried but nothing happened. Did I do something wrong?

main.js :

```
const {app , BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
app.on('ready', function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    mainWindow.on('closed',()=>{
        mainWindow = null;
        });
    mainWindow.webContents.loadFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
    ipc.on('set_token', function(event, arg){ 
   mainWindow.webContents.send('tokens', arg);
});
```

firstfile.js :

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipc.send('set_token', "someValue");
```

secondfile.js :

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
const tes = document.getElementById("send");
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
tes.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var hi = document.getElementById("hi");
    ipc.on('tokens', function(event, arg){
    hi.innerHTML = arg;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is "secondfile.js" included in "index.html" ? Also, have you tried setting breakpoints / debuggers in your code to see where it fails ?

Comment: @Seblor thanks for the comment, yes it works fine excepts it does not give me any answer from that IPC part... and no i want to pass variable between 2 html files separate from index.html, is it that i can only share variable between index.html and something else? can't i share variables between 2 separate html files?

Comment: @Seblor also i dont get any errors thats the frustrating part

Comment: But where are your html files ? you want to share date between 2 html files but are they loaded in browserwindows ? we miss some code.